# load external page in appFramework

Tags: intel-xdk, appframework

I'm using **AppFramework**.

I have a **form.html** page that want to use it in a seprate page, but when I click on  form , it loads with AJAX and inside the index!
what should do I do for loading the form.html page in a separate page?

here is an axample : http://jsbin.com/ziropu/2

when I click on link I want to load page independence of afui!

sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-ignore="true"` in your anchor element this will not load using ajax.

More documentation here: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_anchors

Here is working example:
http://jsbin.com/neguxo/1/edit